# Who is removing my whitespace: Meteor, MongoDB, or Compose.io?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, compose-db

Let's say I update a field like this in a Meteor method:

```
Collection.update({_id: "a"}, {$set: {lalala: "       a b  c     "})
```

I would expect `"       a b  c     "` to turn up as the value in the database, but what is really being saved is `"a b  c"`.

Who is the culprit behind this (or how can I find out?) and how do I get around it?

As I see it, it can either be Meteor, MongoDB, or Compose.io where my database is located.

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of [this question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27200/preserving-whitespace-in-mongodb-values), unless you can actually verify that this value is indeed what is saved.

Comment: 100% that the value without leading and trailing whitespace is being saved. I'm looking at the database through Compose.

Comment: Do you use https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2?

Comment: @Khang Yeah....

Answer (score 3):

If you are using [Collection2](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2), it is responsible for trimming your data automatically. You could turn it off by setting [`trim`](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema#trim) options to `false` when defining schema for your collection.

Comment: I love that that's the default!

Comment: btw, this was a [known bug in simple-schema v1](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema/issues/348) that Aldeed says was fixed in v2. In v1 you could work around it with `autoConvert: false, trim: false` which makes sense if you look at [lines 746-749 of simple-schema.js](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema/blob/v1/simple-schema.js#L746-L749). Please also consider setting `adHominemMode: false`